# Using JDBC to read and update each row

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am able to read each line of a query fine, but I would also like to update a field as they are read.

The following code breaks when I add the two rs.update lines.

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                           ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE)
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
  amount = rs.getInt("amount");
  username = rs.getString("username");

  rs.updateString("processed", "true");
  rs.updateRow();
}
```

It would appear I've found my answer:

[SEVERE] com.mysql.jdbc.NotUpdatable: Result Set not updatable (referenced table has no primary keys).This result set must come from a statement that was created with a result set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, the query must select only one table, can not use functions and must select all primary keys from that table. See the JDBC 2.1 API Specification, section 5.6 for more details.

It won't hurt to add primary keys to my database, probably the right way to do it anyway.

Comment: can you explain more what are you trying to do?

Comment: and paste your error log?

Comment: How does it break? Any exceptions?

Comment: Does your `query`'s selection contains those primary keys? I think that's your JDBC driver complains about.

Comment: @JinKwon Thz u save my life.

Answer (score 0):

I added primary key to my database and it works beautifully.

Thanks!